# Segmentation Fault when Printing Characters in String in C

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I was working on an assignment and noticed I was getting a Seg Fault when I tried printing the individual characters of a string. This is strange because there is no segmentation fault when I remove the print statement.

I simplified that part of the assignment that gave me the Seg Fault in a simpler code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


void printword( char **sptr){

    int i;

    for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i){

        printf( "%c\n", *sptr[i]);
    }
}

int main(){

    char *sentence = "This is my sentence\n";

    printf("Sentence is: %s", sentence);
    printword( &sentence );

}
```

When I run this code, Only the first letter prints, then right after a '?' followed by 'Segmentation fault: 11'. It seems that I can print any character from the string, however, just 1 character is my limit before a seg fault. I don't understand why this is an issue because I am simply printing.

Comment: Is there a reason you're passing a `char**`?

Comment: If in doubt about operator precedence use more `()`.

Comment: Remember this: When changing strings to another one in `C` you pass double pointer when accessing you pass single pointer. Just the side not.

Comment: @Gox Why would you pass a double pointer to edit a string? `strcpy`, `strtok`, `strcat`, etc. don't do that.

Comment: @melpomene sorry wrong wording I  meant swapping string with another one not changing individual characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a precedence issue. `*sptr[i]` parses as `*(sptr[i])`, but you need `(*sptr)[i]`.

It crashes because `sptr[i]` means `*(sptr + i)`, i.e. at `i = 0` you're simply dereferencing `sptr` (giving you `sentence`), then dereferencing that, giving you `*sentence` (i.e. the first character of `sentence`). But at `i = 1` you're doing `sptr[1]` (i.e. `*(sptr + 1)`), which tries to access memory next to the `sentence` variable, then treats it as another pointer to dereference. Even if you're lucky and there happens to be a valid pointer next to `sentence` in memory, successive iterations will just attempt to dereference more and more garbage values as pointers.

Of course, you could avoid the whole problem by having `printword` take a `char *` and simply passing `sentence` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Typical new C programmers mistake, thinking that `*str[i]` is the same as `str[][i]` it is not it is more like `str[i][0]`.

So, why is this happening? When you look at precedence `[]` is at the top. Take a look at [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators_precedence.htm)

The other way to look at it is:

```
arr[i][j]
```

is the like:

```
*(*(arr+i) + j)
```

thus `*str[i]` is like:

```
**(arr + i)
```

what you want is:

```
*(*(arr) + i)
```

which is like:

```
*(arr[i])
```

I hope this helps!!!!

Comment: `str[i][0]` is in fact exactly the same as `*str[i]`, that is how index operator is defined (plus the fact that adding `0` to a valid pointer leaves it unchanged)